# How to have same fixed width for all the column for Interactive report in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have several Interactive reports on my Apex application page, all of them have same columns and column order, but according to the max length of the data for a particular column the column width keeps on changing for different reports, so when someone scroll it doesn't come all aligned, and visually it doesn't look good.

Something like the below image:
[image]

How to have all column to have fix the width? So that my data automatically wrap according to the width of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

- navigate to interactive report **columns**' properties and set **static ID** for each of them (suppose that I have 2 columns, whose static IDs are `IME` and `EVBR`)
- open **page's** properties and put something like this into its **inline CSS** property:

  ```
  th#IME,
    td[headers="IME"] {  
    width: 20em;  
  }  
  th#EVBR,
    td[headers="EVBR"] {  
    width: 20em;  
  }
  ```
- run the page; columns should have the same width now